How to create an underflow in this situation?
So I've got this situation:
a=b*39216/100000
Both a and b are uint8 variables
Is there a value I could assign to b so that a is>100 afterwards?
And then a has to be >100
I've thought about somehow creating an underflow in this situation but can't really see how

The standard defines uint8_t (if that's what you're referring to) as a type that has exactly 8 bits. That means the maximum value it can hold is 255. Since 255 * 3926 is equal to 1000080, then the answer is no: you cannot have a scenario in which a is greater than 100, except maybe in weird implementations on architectures with character types larger than 8 bits and in that case probably relying on a compiler bug and/or undefined behavior.

Good news: If your C implementation has an int width of 18 to 24 bits, you might to able to make this work. With fewer than 18 bits, 39216 and 100000 will be long, which is at least 32 bits, and the expression will be evaluated with long arithmetic with no bounds issues, making the result at most 100. With more than 24 bits, 255•39216 will fit in an int, and the expression evaluation will again be in bounds. With 18 to 24 bits, 39216 and 100000 are int but 255•39216 overflows, so the behavior is not defined by the C standard.

@EricPostpischil Sneaky.  Maybe a PDP-1?

uint8_t a;
uint8_t b;
...
a=b*39216/100000

In this expression, b is integer promoted (Implicit type promotion rules) to type int. Since it started as an unsigned type, all values it can hold will fit inside an int and the promoted result can therefore never be negative.
Since the maximum value that can be contained in a uint8_t is 255, then the expression will at most result in the value 100. The only way to change that would be to change the type of b to a larger type or signed type.
For example:
int8_t b = -128;
a=b*39216/100000;

b is still promoted to int but the sign is preserved. On the right side of = we end up with an int result of -50. This is then converted to uint8_t upon assignment so that the binary representation of 2's complement -50 turns into the unsigned equivalent 0xCE = 206.

I do not know if changing type is allowed

No. As b has to be 257 and max value which can be held by the uint8_t is 255.

I've thought about somehow creating an underflow in this situation but
can't really see how

Unsigned types do not over(under)flow only wraparound.
But if you are lucky you can try implementation-specific behaviour. It will work on the most modern platforms (ARM, x86)
int main(void)
{
    uint8_t a,b = 255;
    a = (b*39216)/(int16_t)100000;
    printf("%"PRIu8"\n", a);
}   

https://godbolt.org/z/dcMTKzrK8

No UB here, just an implementation-defined conversion of 100000 into a int16_t.

@Lundin indeed, amended

first of all you said they are both unsigned and have 8 bits so I will treat them as so.
a max will be the same as b max so a max will be: (255*39216)/100000=100.0008 (rounded down, because that is how C works)
a min will be b min so that will be (0*39216)/100000=0.
from that we can conclude that a has to be between 0 and 100 (including 0 and 100)
in the start I chose b=0xff=255 because that is 8 bits, 0b11111111 = 2**8 - 1.
btw even if a was signed it would not matter because a is always less than 128(where his MSB is 1).
BUT
if b could get negative values (lets say it was signed instead of unsigned) and a would still be signed it is possible for a to be more than 100:
because of negatives
maximum negative value for b in 8 bit is -128=0x80
(-128*39216)/100000 = -50.19648 = -50
and -50=0xCE in an unsigned representation is 206 which is bigger than 100.
summary
In a summary in your case because both a and b are unsigned it is impossible for a to exceed 100.
And any conversion from signed to unsigned or unsigned to signed in the process might cause a to exceed 100.
